# How can I run tests in my build that are under the application project, not a test project?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, msbuild, azure-devops, nunit

I inherited the joy of creating a build for a solution has test files in the application project, not in a test project.

```
MySolution 
    |__MyProject
          |__MyClass.cs
          |__MyClassTest.cs
```

All of the builds I've created previously have had a test project and worked fine with the test task in VSTS. As there is no test assembly, the tests aren't picked up and ran.

I tried the project assembly as the "test assembly" in the build step, but that didn't work. How can I accomplish this?

### Edit

Here are the logs, pointing to the assembly.

```
2018-07-31T18:31:25.0890193Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-07-31T18:31:25.8549638Z NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution started
2018-07-31T18:31:25.8558752Z Running all tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\bin\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.8625176Z NUnit couldn't find any tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\bin\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.9532542Z Running all tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\obj\Release\Before-PostSharp\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.9539232Z NUnit couldn't find any tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\obj\Release\Before-PostSharp\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.9691860Z Running all tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\obj\Release\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.9692255Z NUnit couldn't find any tests in C:\agent\_work\14\s\MyProject\obj\Release\MyProject.dll
2018-07-31T18:31:26.9726008Z NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution complete
```

Comment: Does the project have the appropriate test framework adapters referenced as NuGet packages? There's nothing special in a "test project" vs a regular project that would prevent tests from being discovered, beyond the normal types of problems you'd have with test discovery.

Comment: @DanielMann Appears to. I've added NUnit3TestAdapter, which is what I needed when I ran into a nunit problem in a build that had a test project.

Comment: This should work oob, as @DanielMann says.  Does it work in Visual Studio?  Are you really sure your filters are not excluding this assembly?

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm I would think it would, but it's not. Added the logs. Unless I'm misreading those, it's looking in my `MyProject` assembly for the tests and not finding them.

Comment: Does it work in Visual Studio?

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm actually, no.

Comment: Ok, that's good in fact, easier to fix it in VS :-)   I just tried to set up a command line app in VS, added a test class, + nunit and the adapter and it worked directly.  Setting up VSTS build for the same now, noticed I had to change the filter though.  But irrelevant if it doesnt run in VS, then it is something else.

Comment: I  added a repro to github here: https://github.com/OsirisTerje/ExecutableAsTest  See if that works on your VS.  And then modify it to match whatever you have in your case that doesnt work.   And it works in VSTS build :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177130/discussion-between-yatrix-and-terje-sandstrom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing works regardless of whether this is a test assemble or some other executable.  When something doesn't work out wrt testing, step 1 is to check if it works in Visual Studio, next is to dive into VSTS configuration.
@Yatrix comfirmed it was not working on his Visual Studio either, so I pushed up a repro project at https://github.com/OsirisTerje/ExecutableAsTest  , and from that @yatrix noticed that he was using NUnit 2.6.4 with NUnit 3.10 adapter.   The NUnit 2 and NUnit 3 test frameworks are very different, and use different corresponding adapters.  Running with the NUnit 2 adapter, @yatrix reports back it now works.

Comment: Basically, I'm dumb. ;) Thanks again!